# C Word Count - dealing with paragraphs

Tags: c

Here is my current code:

```
unsigned long charcount = 0;
unsigned long wordcount = 0;
unsigned long linecount = 0;
int n;

for (; (n = getchar()) != EOF; ++charcount) {
    if (n == '\n')
        ++linecount;
    if (n == ' ' || n == '\n' || n == '\t')
        ++wordcount;
    printf("%lu %lu %lu\n", charcount, wordcount, linecount);
}
```

I think there's an issue with this code such that if the text file I'm reading from consists of paragraphs because of the newline that separates them,they would count as words. I'm not sure how I would fix it so that they don't count as words.

Comment: Do you also have to take care of the issue of getting the wrong result when encountering two consecutive spaces?

Comment: @Jongware: I think I can neglect that issue.

Comment: ...and the issue of considering a comma or period as a word separator when the author forgot to use a space. I recommend remembering the previous character, and checking if the next is another separator. This will also solve the paragraph problem.

Comment: @Immortal if you think you can "neglect" significant issues, your code will never be robust. Once a large user base is pushing and abusing it, they will find every possible weakness, as in [Murphy's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy's_law).

Comment: @WeatherVane: Yeah, you're right. I'll think of rectifying my code to account for these situations.

Answer (score 2):

Use indicator which specifies whether you're reading word or whitespace:

```
int isWord = 0;
while ((n = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (isspace(n)) {
        if (n == '\n') ++linecount;
        if (isWord) {
           ++wordcount;
           isWord = 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        isWord = 1;
    }
}
if (isWord)
    ++wordcount;
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using these definitions:

**line beginning**: present character is the first or previous was `'\n'`.
**word beginning**: present character is not a white-space and either it is the first or the previous character was a separator (white-space).

This approach detects the *beginning* of a line/word.

```
unsigned long charcount = 0;
unsigned long wordcount = 0;
unsigned long linecount = 0;
int previous = '\n';
int n;

while ((n = getchar()) != EOF) {
  ++charcount;
  if (isspace(previous)) {
    if (!issspace(n))  ++wordcount;    // Beginning of word detected
    if (previous == '\n') ++linecount; // Beginning of line detected
  }
  previous = n;
}
printf("%lu %lu %lu\n", charcount, wordcount, linecount);
```

This approach work well including the following conditions:

1. Multiple spaces are treat like a single space (separator).
2. File beginning with spaces or not, does not throw off word count.
3. File ending with spaces or not, does not throw off word count.
4. Last line need not end with a `'\n'`.
5. Zero length files are not a problem.
6. No post `EOF` code needed to adjust `line/word` count.
7. No `word/line/char` length limitation other than `ULONG_MAX`.

---

Details on OP's code

```
for (; (n = getchar()) != EOF; ++charcount) {

    // This fails to count the last line of a file should it lack a \n
    if (n == '\n')
        ++linecount;

    // This counts separator (white-space) occurrence.
    // Multiple spaces count as 2 words: not good
    // Files like "Hello" will count as 0 words: not good
    // Files like " Hello " will count as 2 words: not good
    if (n == ' ' || n == '\n' || n == '\t')
        ++wordcount;

    // Using `unsigned long` is good, maybe even `unsigned long long`.
    printf("%lu %lu %lu\n", charcount, wordcount, linecount);
}
```

---

OP it not getting enough "words".  Let us assume and non-letter is a valid word separator.

```
unsigned long charcount = 0;
unsigned long wordcount = 0;
unsigned long linecount = 0;
int previous = '\n';
int n;

while ((n = getchar()) != EOF) {
  ++charcount;
  if (!isalpha(previous)) {
    if (previous == '\n') ++linecount; // Beginning of line detected
    if (isalpha(n))  ++wordcount;    // Beginning of word detected
  }
  previous = n;
}
printf("%lu %lu %lu\n", charcount, wordcount, linecount);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code and it isn't giving me the right output. It's outputting around 100 words too less.

Comment: @Immortal 2nd version append to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store the previous char in a variable and compare.

```
unsigned long int charcount = 0;
unsigned long int wordcount = 0;
unsigned long int linecount = 0;
int n;
int prev='\n';

while ((n = getchar()) != EOF){
    charcount++;
    if (n == '\n' && prev != '\n'){
        linecount++;
    }
    if (n == ' ' || n == '\n' || n == '\t')
        wordcount++;
    }
    prev=n
}
printf( "%lu %lu %lu\n", charcount, wordcount, linecount );
```

Comment: Recommend `if (n == '\n' && prev != '\n'){` --> `if (prev == '\n'){`